# servlet displaying console values to browser

Tags: java, servlets, terminal

I have a servlet program (Got it from a friend), it is executing few command prompt commands and returing the output in console now I would like to see all that multi line console output lines in my browser, how to I do this?

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
      String[] command =
            {
                "zsh",
            };

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
            new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
            PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
            stdin.println("source ./taxenv/bin/activate");
            stdin.println("python runner.py");
            // write any other commands you want here
            stdin.close();
            int returnCode = 0;
            try {
                returnCode = p.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);


}

class SyncPipe implements Runnable
{
public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
      istrm_ = istrm;
      ostrm_ = ostrm;
  }
  public void run() {
      try
      {
          final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
          for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; )
          {
              ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);

          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  private final OutputStream ostrm_;
  private final InputStream istrm_;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to print the output of shell command to browser, so I suggest you can try:

1. Get output stream O from http response object.
2. Pass the O into your SyncPipe as ostrm.
3. Flush the O after p.waitFor().

Just replace these two line:

```
new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), response.getOutputStream())).start();
new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream())).start();
```

I don't have a environment to run your code right now, but I think this change should work. If you get any problem, just feel free to reply here.

Comment: Okay, I seem to have done something wrong, can you show it in code?